# Receive results of select in shell

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell

Ok, I have such script

```
#!/bin/bash
keyOrPass=$1
intercom=$2
flat=$3
number=$4
mysql -ulogin -ppass db_name -e "select cli.codeGuestEmail, cli.codePrivateEmail, cliKey.rf_id, cliKey.emailNotification from mbus_clients as cli join mbusClientKeys as cliKey on cliKey.id_client=cli.id WHERE cli.flat=${flat} and cli.domophone=${intercom};";
php -q sendNotifications.php
```

It works fine, but I should pass some result fields from select into php arguments. Any ideas how to do it?

**OUTPUT:**

```
+----------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+ 
| codeGuestEmail | codePrivateEmail | rf_id      | emailNotification |
+----------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+
|              1 |                0 | 2774490192 |                 0 |
|              1 |                0 | 2774490193 |                 0 |
|              1 |                0 | 2774490194 |                 0 |
|              1 |                0 | 2774490195 |                 1 |
+----------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: wat? why don't you do this in php?

Comment: Is it possible to run php file via inetd?

Comment: Why would you do it this way? If you want to pass along the results then you could write a command line PHP script, or you could access MySQL from PHP. You can run PHP scripts as a service on some Linox OS's.

Comment: Add example output of your select command.

Comment: Output is like this.

Comment: Besides `grep`/`awk` on result of call to mysql, you might call `php -q sendNotifications.php \`mysql ...\`` and parse the result directly in php. (Note the **backticks** in call to php.)

Comment: "Is it possible to run php file via inetd?" - Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql is capable of generating output formatted differently. With the `-B` or `--batch` option, mysql produces the output with TAB as the column separator. The special characters in the fields are escaped (e.g. TAB is output as "\t") so you can use `cut` to extract fields.
Many times in cases like this it's helpful to use the `-N` or `--skip-column-names` option as well, in order to remove column names from the output.